# Transform multiple return values to a custom string in default django admin interface

Tags: python, django

I am returning three variables from a model method and want to display them on the admin interface:

```
def time_since(self):
   time_since = timezone.now() - self.date_opened
   return time_since.days, time_since.seconds//3600, (time_since.seconds//60)%60
```

Getting the value in admin.py

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
    'issue', 
    'time_since',
    )
```

and this is getting displayed as (0,1,21). How do I transform it to 0 days, 1:21 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've returned a tuple (0,1,21) then:

```
x = (0,1,21)

# Assumes that the values in your tuple will always be an integer.
s = '{:d} days, {:d}:{:d}'.format(*x)

print s # 0 days, 1:21
```

The documentation for the string formatting is given [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

**EDIT:** In response to your comment I think you would adjust your code to return the string like so:

```
def time_since(self):
    time_since = timezone.now() - self.date_opened
    out = [time_since.days, time_since.seconds//3600, (time_since.seconds//60)%60]

    # As per Aamir Adnan's suggestion check whether day or days is applicable
    if x[0] == 1:
        return '{:d} day, {:d}:{:d}'.format(*x)
    else:
        return '{:d} days, {:d}:{:d}'.format(*x)
```

Comment: where am I going to put that ?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You might want to have a check for to pluralize word `day` or not. `1 days` will not sound correct.

Comment: @AamirAdnan I've edited the code with your suggestion :) there may be a simpler and more pythonic way of doing it but this should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use django built-in template filter [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) also:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import timesince_filter

def time_since(self):
    return timesince_filter(self.date_opened) # e.g. yield 4 days, 6 hours
```

Comment: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'. Why? I searched around in google and couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Updated my answer. You don't need to subtract dates as the `timesince_filter` will do it for you by looking into your settings `TIME_ZONE`

Comment: Very interesting and useful. But still getting "2 hours, 51 minutes" styling for the date. Not wrong, but not the format I was looking for. Thank you